# pdo_psql doesn't load in MAMP 4.0.1

Tags: php, windows-10, mamp-pro

A few hours ago I installed MAMP Pro 4.0.1 on Windows 10 so far everything was fine until I decided to uncomment pdo_psql.dll inside php.ini to create a connection from PHP to Postgresql but something went wrong, The driver doesn't load it says:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'C:\php\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - The  module can't be found.
 in Unknown on line 0 PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2017 09:24:45) ( ZTS 
 MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP GroupZend
Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. the thing was that the extention dir wasn't uncommented by default settings so I had to uncomment it in php.ini file.

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```